# Blocks of a string and arrays in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

How can I get blocks from a string ( NSString ) and copy then to a array?

```
int BlockSize = 3
char array[3];

NSString *ns = @"ABCDEFGHI";
```

What I want to do is get the the first 3 elements and put on array[0] , the next 3 elements and put then on array[1] , the next 3 on array[2]

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what result you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocks"? Are you looking for `[ns UTF8String]`?

Comment: Well, I want to get the first 3 elements and store in array[0] the next 3 elements and store in array[1] the next 3 and put then in array[2]

Comment: Define "element". Why don't you update your question with actual examples of the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get character from string you can use below code:

```
NSString *ns = @"ABCDEFGHI";
arr[0]= [ns characterAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"%c",arr[0]);

arr[1]= [ns characterAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%c",arr[1]);
```

Or even you go through forloop to iterate to complete string length